# calling a block, things executing out of the expected order

Tags: ruby

while doing the exercise at the bottom of [this](http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/?Chapter=10) page,

I was helped towards the solution you see below:

What continues to vex me though is line 4. It appears that the `block.call` is run in its entirety before `puts` even begins to write to the screen.

Is this just something to accept about Ruby? What do I even call this behavior if I were to try and look it up?

```
def log(desc, &block)
  puts "Beginning #{desc}..."
  #block.call seems to be occurring here!
  puts "... #{desc} finished, returning: #{block.call}"
end

someLittle = lambda {5}

yetAnother = lambda {'I like Thai food!'}

outer = lambda do
  log "some little block", &someLittle
  log "yet another block", &yetAnother
  false
end

log "outer block", &outer
```

Comment: I didn't get your confusion..Is this not giving you the expected output? If so what's is your expected output and what you are getting? Tell these things..

Comment: The way it is written, I would expect it to puts line 2. Then puts line 4, then run all the other blocks which are called by the block.call.

Comment: Instead it is putsing line 2, then skipping the puts on line 4, so it can run and puts all the extra calls entailed by block.call, before finally printing out line 4.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider following example:

```
greeting = "Howdy!"
puts "#{greeting} What's up?"
```

Here you are interpolating `greeting` variable within a string which is passed to Ruby's `Kernel#puts` method. So `greeting` need to be defined and evaluated first before interpolating it (or doing any other operation such as concatenation, etc.).

Do you get it?

Now let's see your example:

```
puts "... #{desc} finished, returning: #{block.call}"
```

Over here too, `desc` and `block.call` needs to be interpreted first before interpolating it within the string.

How about comparing this behaviour with other languages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation

Comment: I saw that it needed to be interpreted early, but I never expected it to be executed early. I guess that's the point of the exercise.